# How to write CLICK function for a Button inside many DIVS using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have this `html` code. I'm trying to show a `table` when the `button` is clicked. It works when button is outside all the `divs`. But I need to write the `click event` when `button` is still inside.

Here's my `HTML` code:

```
                   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-6">
                        <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
                            <img src="images/doctor-new.png" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="">
                            <p><strong class="text-success">All Appointments</strong></p>
                            <button id="click" class="btn btn-success">Show</button>
                            <a >
                                <div class="mask"></div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And here's my `jquery` code:

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function (){
                $('#appointment-table').hide();
                $('div.col-md-4 button#click').click(function (){
                    $('#appointment-table').fadeToggle('slow');
                });
            });
        </script>
```

But it is not working... Can anyone please help?

Comment: $('#click') as a selector could be enough

Comment: But it's not working Sir.... That's why I use something like that (`jquery selectors`)

Comment: You could try $('div.col-md-4').on("click","#click",function(){...

Comment: The truth is, there is no element with the id `appointment-table` within the code provided. In the following JSFiddle, I have changed nothing except for adding a div with the id `appointment-table`: https://jsfiddle.net/066oodg8/1/

Comment: If you reference the button by its ID, ie `$("#click")` and `<button id='click'/>` and there is *only one button with that ID* (because IDs must be unique within the document) *and* your html is not added dynamically (ie after your doc ready) - then it **will** work anywhere.  So if it's not working, one of the above is not correct and your question does not make it clear which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem here, other than the fact that there is no element in your code with the id `appointment-table`.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/066oodg8/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#appointment-table').hide();
  $('div.col-md-4 button#click').click(function() {
    $('#appointment-table').fadeToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-6">
  <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
    <img src="images/doctor-new.png" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail Alt">
    <p><strong class="text-success">All Appointments</strong></p>
    <button id="click" class="btn btn-success">Show</button>
    <a>
      <div class="mask"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="appointment-table">
  Appointment Table
</div>
```

However you may notice a flicker as the `#appointment-table` is hidden; To avoid this use the CSS `display: none;` on the element instead of hiding it with jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.col-md-4 button#click').click(function() {
    $('#appointment-table').fadeToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-6">
  <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
    <img src="images/doctor-new.png" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail Alt">
    <p><strong class="text-success">All Appointments</strong></p>
    <button id="click" class="btn btn-success">Show</button>
    <a>
      <div class="mask"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="appointment-table" style="display: none;">
  Appointment Table
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work Sir... When the button is outside the `div` function works as expected. but in this case, it is not... I'm wondering why.... :(

Comment: @the_dempa Unless you are viewing this from the mobile app, there should be a button that says "Run code snippet". That should run the code I've posted. It seems to work fine for me...

Comment: Yes this is correct and works fine. I even tried adding my code to `fiddle.net`
but in my computer it is not working unless the button is outside the `div`